# How can I close all the others opened dropdowns when opening one using Shopify's Liquid

Tags: javascript, shopify, dropdown, liquid

I would like to implement that on my sidebar dropdowns but Liquid being pretty new to me, I don't seem to find a way to do it.

On JS I would have a `for loop` closing all the items that contains the 'open' class for example then add that class to the single item.

I wish I add tried more but I feel like I don't have the 'Liquid logic' yet..

```
                  <a href="{{ link.url }}"
                    class="mobile-nav__link mobile-nav__link--top-level"
                    id="Label-{{ child_list_handle }}"
                    {% if link.active %}data-active="true"{% endif %}>
                    {{ link.title }}
                  </a>
                  <div class="mobile-nav__toggle">
                    <button type="button"
                      aria-controls="Linklist-{{ child_list_handle }}"
                      {% if link.active or link.child_active %}aria-open="true"{% endif %}
                      class="collapsible-trigger collapsible--auto-height {% if link.active or link.child_active %}is-open{% endif %}">
                      {% include 'collapsible-icons' %}
                    </button>
```

The interesting parts are the `{% if link.active %}`

First, I'm not sure what's setting `link.active` to `true`,
Then I also don't know how I would select these dropdowns element to use them in a loop.

Now what I would like to do is to have a `for loop` that would set `link.active` to `false` on all dropdowns and then setting it to `true` on the single element.

You don't have to give me the total answer, just a way for me to figure out how to select all the elements and what causes `link.active` to be `true`.

Thanks in advance.

[picture of said dropdowns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj3ZL.png)

Comment: `link.active` return true based on the page on which you have, so if you are a collection page and there is the same collection into navigation. Then particular navigation item returns true.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.. On click of the button it sets the element's link's active to true?